# VirtualHost causing ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after installing LetsEncrypt certificates

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

Edit: I took the redirect lines out of the VirtualHosts for the two domains that aren't working.  After rebooting Apache, both the HTTP and HTTPS version of both sites work as intended, but its not automatically redirecting anymore (obviously).  But those same exact redirect rules are working fine for sidmandesign.com

I am migrating my webserver from an IIS server to a LAMP stack using Ubuntu.  I used certbot to install three SSL certificates for my three domains.  Certbot added a -le-ssl.conf file to the virtualhosts directory, so in there I now have (all in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ directory with the proper include inside apache.conf):

sidmandesign.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.sidmandesign.com
   ServerAlias sidmandesign.com
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/Sidman Designs/"
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =sidmandesign.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.sidmandesign.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

sidmandesign-le-ssl.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.sidmandesign.com
    ServerAlias sidmandesign.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/Sidman Designs"

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sidmandesign.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sidmandesign.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

augustinebuilders.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.augustinebuilders.com
   ServerAlias augustinebuilders.com
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/augustine/"
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =augustinebuilders.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.augustinebuilders.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

augustinebuilders-le-ssl.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.augustinebuilders.com
    ServerAlias augustinebuilders.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/augustine"

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/augustinebuilders.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/augustinebuilders.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

salvagedserendipity.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.salvagedserendipity.com
   ServerAlias salvagedserendipity.com
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/salvagedserendipity/"
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =salvagedserendipity.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.salvagedserendipity.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

salvagedserendipity-le-ssl.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.salvagedserendipity.com
    ServerAlias salvagedserendipity.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/salvagedserendipity"

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/salvagedserendipity.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/salvagedserendipity.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Sidmandesign.com works just fine, it redirects to HTTPS and I can see everything.  However when I try the other two sites, they redirect to HTTPS but I get a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in Chrome and a generic cannot display this page in Edge/IE.

Any ideas why one domain would work but the other two don't when configs appear identical?

Comment: What does `Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf` contain?  Verify if you have other redirections in there.

Comment: @Nic3500 No that appears to just have some security and SSL settings.  Nothing about redirects

Answer (score 0):

**Your `RewriteCond` syntax**

In your *:80 VirtualHost, remove your `RedirectCond` and `RewriteRule` directives and add (well, adjust for your domains!):

```
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
```

No need to verify if the domain names match, Apache will only use the configuration in that VirtualHost if the domain matches `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` directives values anyway.

Another point, `RewriteCond` does not need the `=` sign (for future reference):

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www.example.com$
```

---

**Remove `DocumentRoot` in VirtualHost *:80**

Since you never server any content for the *:80 VirtualHost, you should remove `DocumentRoot` directives.

---

**Multiple SSL VirtualHosts problem**

For port 80, no problem you can have many VirtualHosts defined.  Apache will look at the requested domain and use the matching configuration.

But for SSL, that does not work.  Apache cannot read the requested domain until *after* the SSL certificates negotiation is done with the browser.  So what does it do?  It uses the first *:443 VirtualHost it finds.

Ways around this are:

- 1 SSL domain == 1 IP == 1 VirtualHost set for that IP only (i.e. not *:443).  The problem here is you might not have access to more than one address.
- 1 SSL domain == 1 port == 1 VirtualHost set for that port (i.e. *:443, *:444, ...).  The problem here is that port 443 is the default for https sites, so other sites need to be explicitly requested for in the browser, which is counter intuitive for clients.  If you have network infrastructure in front of your Apache, you could change the port there.  `https://www.example.com` is sent to `apache:443`, `https://www.example2.com` is sent to `apache:444`, and so forth.  But this needs to be done *before* the traffic gets to Apache.
- Use SNI in Apache (https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI).

---

**In your case**

- The request `http://<SOMEDOMAIN>`, on port 80 is sent to the proper VirtualHost.
- This VH redirects it to `https://<SOMEDOMAIN>`, on port 443.  Well it should.
- The first VH is always used, so certificate `/etc/letsencrypt/live/sidmandesign.com/fullchain.pem` is the one send to the client's browser.  You can validate this by looking at the browser console and inspecting the certificate.
- The browser thus sees a certificate for one domain, which does not match the requested one (well besides the first domain).

---

**Lastly**

For the *"ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in Chrome"*, look at the console (F12, Network tab, check Preserve logs).  You will see every redirection Chrome got.  This way you will see what is looping.  My guess is that the '=' sign is messing things up.

Comment: I will take a look into this SNI to see if I have it.  The weird part is...if I remove ALL signs of redirects and just have a VH for HTTP and a VH for HTTPS for each domain, as I currently have it, I can manually go to http:// and https:// just fine and the proper certificates load up and everything.  Its just when I try any attempt at a redirect, whether it be mod_rewrite, .htaccess or Redirect permanent, those two domains lead to the infinite loop.  I even tried a test Hello world index.html to make sure it wasn't the content of the page, and it still does it.

Comment: hum, ok.  Have you tried the `Redirect permanent ...` approach I suggested?

Comment: Yes I have tried that.  As a test, I did redirect permanent https://wwww.example.com (4 w's on purpose).  Then, when i went to https://www.example.com, it redirected to https://wwww.example.com, so it appears that even when going to HTTPS version of website, the VirtualHost for port 80 is still going off somehow and I am not sure how or why that is.

Comment: To access the https version you must go to `https://example.com`.  https' port is 443, so a VirtualHost on port 80 should not respond.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might not be suitable to OPs issue, but i had a very similar issue with my wordpress site. So see this as an addition to the answer of Nic3500.
After trying to fix it for a while, i realized that in wordpress there is the possibility to set a site-URL.

In my case the site-URL was example.com
In apache i created a redirect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

The issue was, that wordpress will redirect back to example.com therefore creating a loop of redirections.
After changing the site-URL to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) it works as expected.